# My python code is skipping SQL statements while creating schema and updating foreign keys, please suggest

Tags: python, mysql

I am fairly new to python, I have written a python code that executes Mysql script to "create table schema & add foreign keys" using mysql.connector package.
I am running this script for multiple tables taking 3 sql statements at a time.
The code is executing fine when running on local machine but is missing to create some tables and update foreign keys when running in ISPAN though the execution is successful.

following is **sample script** that I have created:

```
use prime; create table Address(
Address_Uniq_Identifier varchar(25) Not Null
,Address_Locat_Name varchar(50) Not Null
,Address_Line_1 varchar(100) Not Null
,Address_Line_2 varchar(100) Default Null
,Source_Reference varchar(25) Default Null
,Primary Key (Address_Uniq_Identifier));

use prime; create table People(
People_Uniq_Identifier varchar(25) Not Null
,Legal_Entity int(1) Not Null
,Title varchar(20) Default Null
,Last_Name varchar(30) Not Null
,Source_Reference varchar(25) Default Null
,Primary Key (People_Uniq_Identifier));

use prime; create table Account(
Account_Uniq_Identifier varchar(25) Not Null
,Customer_Uniqu_Identifier varchar(25) Not Null
,Primary_Acco_Uni_Identifier varchar(25) Not Null
,Financial_Statu_Code varchar(4) Default Null
,Authorization_Statu_Code varchar(4) Default Null
,Source_Reference varchar(25) Default Null
,Primary Key (Account_Uniq_Identifier));

use prime; create table Customer(
Customer_Uniq_Identifier varchar(25) Not Null
,People_Uniqu_Identifier varchar(25) Not Null
,Customer_Type int(5) Not Null
,Source_Reference varchar(25) Default Null
,Primary Key (Customer_Uniq_Identifier));

use prime; Alter table Customer
 ADD FOREIGN KEY (People_Uniqu_Identifier)  REFERENCES People (People_Uniq_Identifier);
```

Following is the **code snippet**:

```
    //Reading file       
    //Making SQL connectivity      
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="**7.*.*.1",
        user="r**t",
        password="N***a@*0*1",
        database="prime"
        )   
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()   
    //Creating script   
    //Executing script 3 at a time using the following code in loop   
    mycursor.execute(record_exe)  //*executing the first 3 sql stmt   
    mycursor.fetchall()   
    mycursor.close()              //* closing sql cursor   
    mydb.close()                  //* closing database connectivity   
    record_exe = ""   //* initialising the sql statement with spaces   
    count_semi =0    
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="**7.*.*.1",              //* creating the connectivity again
    user="r**t",
    password="N***a@*0*1",
    database="prime"
    )    
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()      //* creating a new cursor    
    time.sleep(5)                 //* added sleep time to counter for lag on ISPAN
```

the issue comes when I run this code on ISPAN, though it executes fine but some tables are missing and foreign key updates are not done.
kindly help suggest a way to check why it is skipping some sql commands

Comment: I do not see COMMIT. *executing the first 3 sql stmt* I see 10 statements, what 3 of them are executed?

Comment: Hi Akina
Thanks for your reply but it is giving me "commands out of Sync" error when I am  placing the mydb.commit() command after mycursor.execute().         

The first 3 sql statements means that the code is executing 3 sql statements at a time going in loop (the sql statements that are generated as part of the script)